# ASP.NET MVC select question

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a model, in the model a method such as,

```
public Pages GetPage(int? id)
{            
    return _dataContext.Pages.First(p => p.id == id);
}
```

If I pass the wrong parameter (like 123333-no record it database), it throws an exception,

> Sequence contains no elements

What is the correct code version, or can try and catch simply be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming Pages is a reference type, in which case default<T> is null:

```
public Pages GetPage(int? id)
{
    return _dataContext.Pages.FirstOrDefault(p => p.id == id);
}
```